# How to click user and view the user data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am doing a project with VueJS and I need to the following:

Use an API & fetch a list of users in the home page.

When clicking on a user's button, I need to redirect to another component & output that user's details in that component (only the details of the user that I clicked).

Here is the table displaying the users info

```html
 <v-data-table hide-actions flat :headers="headers" :items="doctors">
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.profile.full_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.updated_at }}</td>
         <td> 
          <v-btn outline small color="indigo" @click="view(props.item)">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> &nbsp; make payment
                            </v-btn>
         </td>


        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-results>
          <h6 class="grey--text">No data available</h6>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

the view function is in the methods

```js
 view() {
            window.open(`/finance/pay-doctors/${item.id}`, "_blank");
        },
```

I have created a dynamic route

```js
 { path: '/finance/pay-doctors/:id', component: DoctorDetails}
```

Am unable to create the DoctorDetails and show data

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try with a router push initially.
Hence please use

```html
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        view(id) {
            this.$router.push({ path: `/finance/pay-doctors/${item.id}` })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Make sure that your router is properly set + that you have the proper state thanks to your Vue devtools.

Also, be sure to have something to fetch the user's data on `DoctorDetails`.