# How to open a new page with the props id of a specific user on blank page and set route

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a code have fetched from the laravel backend and passed it to vue frontend. the data is a table with records. I have already implemented it.
I have a payment tab which i want it to redirect to a specific page using the id to display data of the individual.

[image: This is the table format i want when i click the make payment to open a new page with the user details]

I have tried the router-push how do i implement it

this is my implementation code

```
<template>
 <v-data-table hide-actions flat :headers="headers" :items="doctors" :pagination.sync="pagination"
        :rows-per-page-items="pagination.rowsPerPageItems"
        :total-items="pagination.totalItems">
    
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.full_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ 'Doctor' }}</td>
          <td><button class="disabled btn btn-success">amount</button></td>

         <td> 
          <v-btn outline small color="indigo" @click="view(props.item)">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> &nbsp; make payment
                            </v-btn>
         </td>
         
     
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-results>
      <h6 class="grey--text">No data available</h6>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
  <div class="text-center">
          <v-pagination
            v-model="page"
            :length="4"
            circle
          >
        </v-pagination>
         </div>
     </div>
</template>


<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      dateFormat: "DD MMM, YYYY",
      selected: null,
      dialog: false,
      loading: false,
      saveLoader: false,
      pagination: {
      descending: true,
      page: 1,
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      sortBy: 'fat',
      totalItems: 0,
      rowsPerPageItems: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    },
      headers: [
        {text: "#", value: ""},
        {text: "name", value: "name"},
        {text: "email", value: "email"},
        {text: "role", value: "role"},
        {text: "updated_at", value: "updated_at"},
        {text: "Action", value: "action"},
      ],
    };
  },


  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      doctors: "getListDoctors",

    }),
   
  },


  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
     fetchDoctors: 'setListDoctors'
      
    }),

    view() {

      console.log(this.doctors)
            // window.open(`/finance/pay-doctors/${item.id}`, "_blank");
        },


  },
 async mounted() {
  await this.fetchDoctors();
  },

}

</script>
```

Comment: You already asked the same question here ? [How to click user and view the user data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74342886/how-to-click-user-and-view-the-user-data)

Comment: yah i reformatted for readability

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
let routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'routeName', query: {data: "someData"}});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```